# GMX.COM Send email with alias in POP3,IMAP client

Tags: email, imap, pop3

We know gmx.com supports to create up to 10 alias for 1 account. At the web-base client, when we reply or compose email, we are able to switch the alias.

So I wonder if I can do so in POP3,IMAP client like thunderbird.

I don't want to add all aliases to my clients because when there has new email the client will receive duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

It works perfectly via IMAP with thunderbird.

When composing/replying click the dropdown menu of the email address (From field), pick "Customize From Address...", confirm with OK, and type any of your aliases. It will be accepted.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. From [answer] "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better", i.e. you might add links to the related help artciles from gmx.com about how to set up clients like  Thunderbird.